# How to show all apps receives strings in "Open In.." menu?

Tags: ios

I'm totally new in iOS development. I'm developing an app processing some strings in UItextview. After the process, I want show "Open In.." menu with all applications can receive text values.
To explain more. What I mean is like this in Android http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: You use `UIActivityViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at the link you posted.

Apple enforces a "sandbox" around apps which greatly limits what you can do.

Off the top of my head here are a few ways to do it:

Define a custom URL scheme in each of your apps. One app would open a URL using the other app's URL scheme, and that would open the other app and pass it the URL.

For a family of apps from the same company you should also be able to set up a common base "bundle ID" and use that to read and write shared entries to the keychain. The keychain is limited to fairly short bits of data however. (It's intended for password strings and the like.)

I haven't used it before, but you should also be able to use the UIDocumentInteractionController class to pass a copy of a document between apps. As I understand it, the sending app presents a document and asks the user to pick an app with which to open the document. When the user picks a target app, the system creates a copy of the document in the target app's documents directory and then tells the target app to open it.

Comment: Thanks, I can say now there's no way to let the application do this kind of calling. Thanks again Duncan.